# -bash: mysql: command not found

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have looked around at other questions that have been posed and they seem to all have the same answer however my issue seems to be unique.

I have installed MySQL to use in an Angular project and have been trying to run `mysql -u root -p` in order to get things moving but it throws back `-bash: mysql: command not found` even though I have also done `export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin` inside of my bash_profile.

This seems to be where it ends for a lot of troubleshooting but it seems I have something else wrong. I have tried adjusting the bash profile to where it is just `export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql` just to see if it would work and there wasn't any difference so I changed it back.

My next thought it uninstalling MySQL and reinstalling but I wanted to see if there was a command I am missing.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all I needed to do was `source ~/.bash_profile` so it would reload my profile environment.